# SpriteKit and swift game

Tags: swift, ios8, sprite-kit, game-physics

I am kind of new to SpriteKit and I am using Swift language.
Here is my issue..

In the attached image , the BasketBall and Ring is a SkSpriteNode type.

1. The physicsBody?.dynamic is set to false for the the Ring
2. The physicsBody?.dynamic is set to true for the the BasketBall.

as expected the ball moves around the screen and also bounces when hits the corner or bottom. The ball also bounces when it hits the Ring , which is good to some extent.

Now I would like to make the ball pass through the ring if it is at a proper location...just like in basket ball game. How to accomplish this ?

[image]

Comment: Tricky, because you're essentially trying to do 3D physics with a 2D physics engine. You would have to determine whether the approach angle of the ball is correct before or when it hits the ring, then decide to remove the collision of the ring altogether until the ball passed through. You can not have the ball, say, swirl around on the ring and eventually fall through. Consider that your graphics have perspective, but the physics don't. It's like (real world analogy) trying to make something fall through a coin, but you can only remove the coin entirely.

Comment: is there a way to track the position points of the moving SKSpriteNode ?

Comment: split the ring into two sprites; the tope half (behind the ball) and the bottom half(in front of the ball). Do not give either of those sprites physics bodies. Add two nodes with round physics bodies, one at each side of the ring. The ball can pass between these bodies.